# update database on click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, haml

hi i am trying to update a value within my database (PostgreSQL) when a user clicks a certain link, though what i have is working, i dont think its best practice. if anyone can show how i could better achieve this would be great

view

```
%ul.button-group.round.even-3
          %li= link_to '<i class="general foundicon-checkmark"></i>'.html_safe, accept_availability_path(a), :method => 'put', :remote => true, :class => 'button success tiny', :id => a.id, :disable_with => ''
```

controller

```
    def accept
    @availability = Availability.find(params[:id])
    @availability.available= true

    respond_to do |format|
      if @availability.update_attributes(params[:availability])
        format.html { render :nothing => true }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

routes

```
resources :availabilities do
    put 'accept', :on => :member
    put 'decline', :on => :member
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing particularly wrong with what you're doing. Your controller doesn't need to use update_attributes, you aren't passing any attributes into it. You can just `save` it with the change to `.available`

```
def accept
  @availability = Availability.find(params[:id])
  @availability.available = true

  respond_to do |format|
    if @availability.save
      format.html { render :nothing => true }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

You could neaten your routes like so:

```
resources :availabilities do
  member do 
    put :accept 
    put :decline
  end
end
```

Comment: is there a better way to use the link/route?

Comment: They look absolutely fine. Your routes could be streamlined a little, answer updated. Your link is fine, `link_to_remote` used to be the way to do these but was deprecated in rails 3 in favour of `:remote => true`.

Comment: though do i need use use `:method => 'put'` in my link?

Comment: You do indeed, if you don't put it there link_to defaults to `get` even if it's remote.

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane was this any use to you? Some further details on `link_to` can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) - you've used it correctly though :)